# Python google cloud function deployment failure - websockets

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt, gemini

I am trying to deploy a python script from Google source code and it is failing when attempting to import `create_connection` from the websockets library.

Here is the top of my script. It fails during import of the gemini package, which in turn is importing websockets:

```py
import json
import os

from gemini import PrivateClient
```

and my `requirements.txt`

```
gemini-python==0.2.1
```

The Google Cloud Functions log shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_cli())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli
    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 255, in create_app
    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gemini
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gemini/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .basewebsocket import BaseWebSocket
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gemini/basewebsocket.py", line 9, in <module>
    from websocket import create_connection, WebSocketConnectionClosedException
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_connection' from 'websocket' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/__init__.py)
```

This script runs on my Mac using Python 3.8. Not sure what to do as this seems environment specific. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not support WebSockets.

You may want to consider an alternative compute service such as Cloud Run which [does](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets)

Comment: So I should clarify, I don't need websockets and don't need the websocket functionality that the gemini library has to do what I want to do. Maybe I need to learn how to monkey patch websockets out of my script.

Comment: @Randy If you are not able to monkey patch websockets out of your script, you might try to submit a feature request in this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=1163154) asking to add support for Websockets in order to be able to get rid of that ImportError.